# unable to upload the image

Tags: php, image

I am trying to update the image and only the db path is getting updated and not the files, i am able to collect the $_FILES array successfully but the file is not updating to image folder

my folder structure is

root->image
    ->function/update.php

**update.php**

```
static function addimage($post,$files){

                unset($post['imgupload']);
                $filename=$files['imgpath']['name'];
                if(!empty($filename)){
                    $tmp_name=$files['imgpath']['tmp_name'];

                    $dst='../image/'.$filename;
                    move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $dst);
                    $post['imgpath']=$filename;
                }

                $r= sql query to update the filepath in db
                return is_numeric($r->id)?'true':'false';
            }
```

can anyone help me out.

Comment: What is the return from `move_uploaded_file`? Does the directory exist? Does it have the correct file permissions?

Comment: Do not trust user provided filename, it could be used for directory traversals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code

`$dst= dirname(dirname(__FILE__)).'/image/'.$filename;`

instead of

`$dst='../image/'.$filename;`

Comment: I updated its returning bool true but file is not uploadingg

Comment: you are champ :) Thanks ...

Answer (score 0):

you are using it wrong

change

```
 $filename=$files['imgpath']['name'];
    $tmp_name=$files['imgpath']['tmp_name'];
```

to

```
$filename=$_FILES['imgpath']['name'];
$tmp_name=$_FILES['imgpath']['tmp_name'];
```

Answer (score 0):

i) Make sure that you have added `enctype="multipart/form-data"` to your form.

ii) `$_FILES` is the correct syntax.

iii) Check for any file permission issue.

Refer a helpful link to check if you are doing some mistake -
http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php

Also, try with giving the full path instead of a relative path.

Comment: Yes, I am submitting the form as you mentioned...I am passing $_FILES as arg to func fun_name($post,$files){} .. So all are checked as fine..